# I want to add custom tag defined in docisign on my document through REST API call in Apex

Tags: rest, docusignapi, apex

I want to add AccountName custom tag defined in docusign on my document through REST API call in Apex. Here is my REST API request body

```
{
  "status" : "sent",
  "customFields" : {
    "textCustomFields" : [ {
      "name" : "AccountName",
      "show" : "true",
      "required" : "False",
      "value" : "Test Account",
      "customFieldType" : "text"
    } ]
  }
}
```

The URL is https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/'accountId'/envelopes

I use anchor string /txtAccountName1/ which I have added on my document but it does not map to any value of the custom field AccountName related to salesforce object. For the tabs it works fine it successfully maps the signer tag to s1 and date to the d1 but for this custom field it does not map the AccountName custom tag to the anchor string /txtAccountName1/. I have created the custom tag AccountName related to salesforce object and used anchor string as /txtAccountName{r}/. I am writing the code in sandbox and using Docusign Demo Account for the integration.I am not sure about the name used in textCustomField and value I used is the reason for not getting the required result. Though the Rest API request is returning the sucess.

How can I map the AccountName value to the anchorString defined in my document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two things customtab and customfields. CustomFields is the metadata on an envelope, there is no tab for this and you can send text type of list type custom fields, these type of fields are not visible to a signer/recipient and is sent as metadata in an envelope, For details related to CustomFields are available at https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields/create/

Now customTab, if you have already defined an account level customTab as "AccountName" then you can add them using REST API using below call like:

```
{
    "textTabs": [{
        "tabLabel": "AccountName",
        "documentId": "83644555",
        "recipientId": "84066562",
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "value": "AccountName",
        "anchorString": "/txtAccountName1/"
    }]
}
```

So before using the Accountlevel custom tab, you need to create it in your DocuSign account from webapp or using API - https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/CustomTabs/CustomTabs/create/, Once it is created then only you can use it in an envelope.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't pull in the custom tag definition. You need to define the entire tag every time you use it, which means you'll need to use something like this:

```
"textCustomFields" : [ {
  "name" : "AccountName",
  "show" : "true",
  "required" : "False",
  "value" : "Test Account",
  "anchorString": "/txtAccountName1/"
  "customFieldType" : "text"
} ]
```